# Equivalent of export command in Windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, command-line, bash, export

I am following a documentation and executing some commands in Windows 10 command prompt:

```bash
export OPENAI_LOG_FORMAT='stdout,log,csv,tensorboard'
export OPENAI_LOGDIR=path/to/tensorboard/data

tensorboard --logdir=$OPENAI_LOGDIR
```

I have figured that `export` is a Unix command and the equivalent in Windows is `setx`. I have executed the first two commands and when I tried the third command, `$OPENAI_LOGDIR` is not properly detected. Can someone help with the equivalent of these in Windows?

Comment: if running script under cmd.exe use %<EnvVarName> to reference it: echo %OPENAI_LOG_FORMAT

Comment: **setx OPENAI_LOG_FORMAT 'stdout,log,csv,tensorboard'** makes a "user variable" **setx OPENAI_LOG_FORMAT 'stdout,log,csv,tensorboard' /m** makes a "system variable". **Note: No equal sign is used.** Variables created with `setx /m` will be available in the next cmd window you open but will not be available in the current window. Use `setx` if you want the variable to be available in the current window.

Comment: Hi I understood about the setx, how do I access that variable for the third command. `$OPENAI_LOGDIR` is not fetching the variable value

Comment: TWI is unfortunately not entirely correct. In `cmd`, the syntax is `%VariableName%`. So, `%OPENAI_LOGDIR%`. Also, you might want to consider `set` instead of `setx`, depending on your use case.

Comment: you said that it's not working but you didn't show your code. You must show what you've tried

Comment: just found an exact duplicate [Windows equivalent of $ in unix commands](https://superuser.com/q/1500487/241386) regarding the above commands of OPENAI_LOG_FORMAT and OPENAI_LOGDIR

Answer (score 13):

`setx` is **not** the counterpart of Linux `export` in Windows. `export` just makes the variable available **temporarily** to the *current shell and its children processes* whereas `setx` stores the variable **permanently** to *every user or system process in the future*.

You didn't show all the real commands you used so based on the comments I guess you ran these

```
setx OPENAI_LOG_FORMAT 'stdout,log,csv,tensorboard'
setx OPENAI_LOGDIR path/to/tensorboard/data
tensorboard --logdir=$OPENAI_LOGDIR
```

which is absolutely wrong!!!

First `setx` is supposed to be **run only once**, thus if you want to set the environment for the current session then you must use `set` instead of `setx`. If you do want to set the variable permanently then you'll still need to **restart the shell** so the changes apply, and never run the command again

Besides [single quote isn't a quoting character in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24173825/995714) so you'll need to remove `''` and use `stdout,log,csv,tensorboard`, or use double quotes `"stdout,log,csv,tensorboard"` if your program does quote removal by itself

And lastly, variables in cmd are accessed with `%%` instead of `$` like bash, hence you must change the last line to `tensorboard --logdir=%OPENAI_LOGDIR%`. The final result is like this

```
set "OPENAI_LOG_FORMAT=stdout,log,csv,tensorboard"
set "OPENAI_LOGDIR=path/to/tensorboard/data"

tensorboard --logdir=%OPENAI_LOGDIR%
```

This is still a guess until you provide enough information in the question

Answer (score 12):

you can try this:

in PowerShell

```
$env:OPENAI_LOGDIR="path/to/tensorboard/data"
```

in cmd

```
set OPENAI_LOGDIR=path/to/tensorboard/data
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your computer

1. Search for this PC icon
2. Click on with the right button than choose properties.
3. Click on Advanced System Settings (left part)
4. Click on Environment Variables (right-down)
5. Add a new system variable and save the changes

Now it will work for all users. To test open the cmd and type `echo %your_variable%`

for more information, see [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: There’s no need to create persistent environment variables for everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to include this in programs, below is what is done in python:

```python
import os

os.environ["OPENAI_LOG_FORMAT"] = 'stdout,log,csv,tensorboard'
os.environ["OPENAI_LOGDIR"] = path/to/tensorboard/data
```